# Why does the direction of a coefficient reverse when accounting for a moderation interaction?

Tags: mediation, path-model, interaction

I'm conducting a moderated mediation analysis. On their own, the bivariate correlation between X and M is positive. However, when I calculate the full path analysis with the moderator (W), the interaction effect of the moderator (XW) is a positive predictor of M, but now X is a negative predictor of M. I'm not sure how to interpret or report this; please help!

Comment: Moderated mediations are pretty complex (and there's more than one kind). Do you understand how this can happen with regular moderation?

Comment: The instance I cite in my description is an example of regular moderation I suppose but no I don't understand how this happens; could you explain?

Comment: You have three X, moderator and Y. X -> Y is positive. Then add the moderator. Effect from X -> Y is the predicted effect of X when M is zero. M might not be able to be zero. E.g. M might be age, which went from 20 to 40 in your study.

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate it. I'm still unsure how the sign for the effect of X->Y can go from significantly positive to significantly negative and remain interpretable. Is it standard to ignore direct effects when doing modertation analysis?

Comment: The term direct effect is from mediation, not moderation. Do you mean main effect?

Comment: One way to think about moderation is that the slope is the outcome. So the effect from X ->  Y depends on M. If you don't include M in the model, the effect from X -> Y is (approx) the effect at the mean of X. If there's a positive moderation, that means that the slope from X -> Y increases as M increases. And if M decreases, the slope goes down. If  M goes down enough, the X -> Y effect will be zero. And if M goes down further, the X -> Y effect will be negative.